# export CSV file with arabic words android

Tags: java, android, csv, gson, export-to-csv

I'm Exporting a JSON to csv file using open csv library but the Arabic words show as this format ÙØ²Ø®Ø¨Ø§ÙØ²Ø.

I tried to encode the JSON with "ISO-8859-1" and decode it with "UTF-8" but the result is the words start to appear in this ??????? and in CSV I used
UTF-8 as a StandardCharsets.

```
 //Convert Data to JSON:

   JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
   try {
       for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
           DoctorReports doctorReports = d.getValue(DoctorReports.class);
           Gson gson = new Gson();
           String response = gson.toJson(doctorReports);
             //String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(response, "ISO-8859-1");
            // response = URLDecoder.decode(encoded, "UTF-8");
           jsonArray.put(new JSONObject(response));
       }
       saveCsv(jsonArray);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
```

}

```
    // How I write to CSV File 
     CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(
           new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), 
               StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
        CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR
       );
   String[][] arrayOfArrays = new String[outerArray.length()][];
   for (int i = 0; i < outerArray.length(); i++) {
       JSONObject innerJsonArray = (JSONObject) outerArray.get(i);
       String[] stringArray1 = new String[innerJsonArray.length()];
       stringArray1[0] = (String) innerJsonArray.getString("doctorName");
         stringArray1[1] = (String) innerJsonArray.getString("hospital");
         stringArray1[2] = (String) innerJsonArray.getString("specialty");
       arrayOfArrays[i] = stringArray1;
       writer.writeNext(arrayOfArrays[i]);
   }
   writer.close();
```

Comment: you have to decode using the same charset used to encode.

Comment: Just use UTF-8 throughout.  ISO-8859-1 is unable to encode Arabic.

Comment: @jhamon I tried the same charset to encode an decode but it's produce an empty file

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I used UTF-8 to encode and decode but also it produce an empty file

Comment: in your "//Convert Data to JSON:" part, encoding then decoding is useless. You don't show how the two codes parts are related. First builds a JSONArray of String, second seems to use an array of JSONObject

Comment: @jhamon Ahh, sorry I just noticed that I may delete it when I tried to fix the problem, I edited the code now but the problem remains

Comment: Your code is strange. You have a valid object instance, you serialize it to a JSON object just to extract some attributes from this JSON object. Simply remove all the JSON and use getters on your object: `doctorReports.getDoctorName()`

Comment: @jhamon yes, you're right I am working on it.